# Nearly duplicate symbols from readelf at same address

Tags: c++, linux, linker, readelf

I am using readelf to figure out why a binary is so large, but I am confused about the output. Or my binary is linked very wrongly. Right now the binary is approximately 380MB, and if I do this:

> readelf -W -s binary |  awk 'NR > 3 { sum += $3 } END { print sum }'

I get 236221726 bytes. Seems low, but maybe I'm missing static symbols or what not. But if I do:

> readelf -W -s binary | sort -n -r -k 3 | less

I see this:

> 172766: 000000000cf8d960 99993 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 symbolA
>
> 147338: 000000000cf8d960 99993 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 symbolB
>
> 132791: 000000000cf8d960 99993 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 symbolA
>
> 107363: 000000000cf8d960 99993 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 symbolB

Where symbolA and symbolB are only 1 char different, and demangle to the same thing.

So, my questions:
1) If those things have the same address, are there actually four copies in my binary? 
2) If there aren't four copies, and these are aliases, shouldn't readelf report that? 
3) If the are four copies, how and why? I assume I'm doing something bad linkage-wise.
4) If there aren't four copies, then the summed size from readelf is waaaaay below the actual size of the binary - why?

Edit: Adding some more information... The above readelf output was from the fully linked binary. Looking at just the .o that contains symbolA/symbolB, readelf still reports 1 copy of each symbolA and symbolB, at the same address.

*but* if I objdump -d the .o file, I only see assembly for symbolA.

So - is objdump or readelf "wrong"?

Answer (score 0):

If you place a function **definition** in a header and then include this header in different source files, a different function will be generated for every inclusion (well, unless it's inlined everywhere in a particular source file). It's hard to tell without looking at your sources, but that might be the case.

Consider moving big non-inlinable functions in separate source files, leaving only **declaration** in the corresponding headers. This might do the trick.

Comment: The function that symbolA/B decode to is not in a header file, but in a cpp file.

Comment: @BraxtonThomason Yeah, that makes sense. But the actual addresses of the symbols are all equal - these are all pointing to `000000000cf8d960`. Did you consider to remove debug symbols from your binary?

Comment: This is compiled with -O3 and without -g.